# Excel Interop AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData)

I am getting this by calling

```
myRangeObj.Insert(CopyOrigin: XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);
```

And Excel just crashes right after.

The behavior is rather interesting. If I do not attach to a debugger Excel just crashes and no global exception handler being hit. In event viewer the entry is

> Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4867.1000, time
>   stamp: 0x57d799c6
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23543, time stamp: 0x57d2fde1
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000724a8
>   Faulting process id: 0x1720
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d241b7c6c06d70
>   Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
>   Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id:2974b4d0-adab-11e6-828a-44850096768d

If I do attach to a debugger sometimes I can get the AccessViolationException throw right after `TargetInvocationException`.

If I try to add a try catch block around that line Visual studio would crash and the catch block code would not get hit

This issue is only reproducible on some machines and we have noticed that `Application.Calculate()` call might cause this as well.

This issue has been reproduced in Windows 7, Windows 10 and Windows Server 2008 all with 32 bit Excel 2013

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: These `AccessViolationExceptions` are extremely hard to analyze. Yesterday I had a very similar one during some innocent `ribbonUI.ActivateTab(...)` on Excel 2013/Windows 10. I analyzed the memory dump in WinDbg for 3 hours just to see that deep in the mso.dll the instruction pointer gets 0x0, which basically just means that there's a `NullReference` somewhere. But good luck finding the cause when there are no symbols available for excel.exe/mso.dll. I had similar ones before and I discovered that most of them are related to timing problems if you do something when Excel isn't expecting that.

Comment: @haindl do you think it might has something to do with allocating bunch COM object without freeing them?

Comment: That's certainly possible! There are so many mysterious things happening if you don't release all your COM objects. I didn't do that in the past as well with the result that Excel crashed if it had a Word document embedded in it. Crazy stuff... But as soon as I released **all** of them everything was working fine. I looked in my documentation and I had one `AccessViolationException` in Excel 2013 after patch day on 2015-09-08 where a simple call of `range.HasFormula` or `range.HasArray` just "poisons" the whole process and causes the `AccessViolation` to happen later when doing normal things.

Comment: I found a workaround for `HasFormula` (with a quirky check of `Formula`) but I have no workaround for `HasArray` to this day. The extreme difficulty comes from the fact that your original call may or may not be directly responsible for the `AccessViolationException`. I found all my countless solutions only by trial-and-error after commenting out everything and then re-enable statement after statement. I'm developing Excel COM/VSTO add-ins for many years now and my documentation is really full - especially with references to `AccessViolationExceptions`. You may try to analyze the memory dump.